# How to add text to a C# datagrid from a textbox using a button click

Tags: c#

How to add text to a C# datagrid from a textbox using a button click

Comment: hey look at this there's something called google and MSDN

Answer (score 1):

in the button's click event handler, add a row (assuming you want to add a row) to the datagrid with the contents from the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give more information.  Do you have a DataTable bound to the DataGrid already?  Have you created columns in the DataTable?  Are you sure it's not actually a DataGridView (the .net 2.0 + version of DataGrid)?  Is it ASP or Winforms?